# Find/Replace broke my application (reckless mistake)

Tags: android, fill-parent, find-replace

Out of patience I did one of the things that you're not supposed to do unless you are **ABSOLUTELY SURE**. I wasn't absolutely sure and now I'm paying for it.

**What Happened**

My outdated app is using `fill_parent` as an attribute for `android:layout_height`. `fill_parent` is deprecated so I'm switching everything to `match_parent`. You can probably guess what happened next...

I was wreckless with the `Android Studio` find & replace tool. Wreckless "undo" is limited. To make it worse I did another find & replace to reverse the situation so here is what is going on:

**The Problem**

`error: cannot find symbol variable fill_parent`

I replaced `fill_parent` with `match_parent` and by doubling back and replacing `match_parent` with `fill_parent` I've ended up replacing much needed deep-level references of to the point where `fill_parent` isn't even recognized anymore. Worst case I will make a copy of where I'm at, grab the previous version in the repo, and figure out what all changed. Is there a less time-consuming way to do this or am I stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all the Apple products because we work with them most but I love the competition Google / Samsung / Microsoft bring and collectively I like the competition better. That being said, Apple saved the day on this one.

## Time Macine

*auto backup was 10 minutes before the "mishap"*

If you're not familiar, [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(OS_X)) is a product that **Apple** created to combat issues like the one I ran into today. *Most* consumers don't have the know-how of `GIT` / `SVN` so when they delete files they are *permanently* gone unless they have luck with a drive [deep scan](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=what%20is%20a%20hard%20drive%20deep%20scan). `Time Machine` is a good project and if you use `OS X` then I strongly suggest you purchase and external drive and make it a `Time Machine` backup.